# My Ubuntu stopped connecting to wi-fi out of nowhere, but wi-fi works on windows

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, connection

I've been using Ubuntu for a little less than a year and everything was OK until out of nowhere I turn my PC on in the morning and Ubuntu doesn't connect to my wi-fi, I also tried to connect to my phone's hotspot and it also didn't work.

This is what shows up when I run the `lshw -C network` command (excuse the quality):

[image: photo from my phone]

For context, I am dual booting with Windows and the connection on Windows is just fine, I tried to fix this with following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rc7lZV_xvTU) but it didn't work, can anyone please help me?

Edit: I solved the problem by inserting my USB that had the ubuntu downloading software burned into it and choose try ubuntu and it connected to wi-fi, when i disconnected the USB and went back to my actual ubuntu on my pc it was connecting lol

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i mt79` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.